# Change background image of UIImage added in UInavigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have created a UIView, added the ImageView that UIView as a subview and the add my uiview to navigation controller. here is my code for that:-

```
UIView* VwTopHdr=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0.3, 1024, 122)];

header_bgimageview =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0.3, 1024, 122)]; 

header_bgimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerBack.png"];

[VwTopHdr addSubview:header_bgimageview];
[header_bgimageview release];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:VwTopHdr];
```

Now i want to change the background image of "header_bgimageview" at rune time depending on my code conditions.here i write code to change image:-

```
header_bgimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Differntimage.png"];
```

But i am not able to change background image using above line of code. What i have to do is removing my UIView from navigation controller create again and the  added on navigation controller.

Why i am not able to change image directly instead of creating and added my view again on controller.How can i change image directly?

Expecting for your favourable reply.

Comment: Is `header_bgimageview` `nil` when you try to set the new image

Comment: @Paul:- No it is not nil i have chacked into code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which will basically invalidate the view

```
[VwTopHdr setNeedsDisplay];
```

Per class reference documentation on UIView:

**setNeedsDisplay**

Marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn.
- (void)setNeedsDisplay